# syntax error near unexpected token `(' when executing in perl script

Tags: perl, syntax-error

I have this command that I can run at a command prompt:

```
sed \'/SOAP service initialization completed/ q\' <(exec tail -n +0 -f /Users/xxxx/Desktop/sample.txt); kill $! 2> /dev/null
```

Which works fine. It tails the sample file and quits when it encounters the "SOAP service initialization completed" message. When I try to execute this in a perl script

```
\#!/usr/bin/perl

my $tail_command = qq{sed \'/SOAP service initialization completed/ q\' <(exec tail -n +0 -f /Users/xxxx/Desktop/sample.txt); kill \$! 2> /dev/null;};

system($tail_command);
exit;
```

I get this error

```
sh: -c: line 0: `sed '/SOAP service initialization completed/ q' <(exec tail -n +0 -f /Users/xxxx/Desktop/sample.txt); kill $! 2> /dev/null;'
```

Comment: Perl is using "sh" to run the command, but I'm guessing your command prompt is NOT sh, maybe bash or something else.  Does it work if you run it directly in sh?  If not, does it work if you escape the parentheses?

Comment: There's no way that `sed \'/SOAP service initialization completed/ q\'` "works fine".

Comment: As for your question, the command isn't a valid `sh` command (as you can see with `sh -c 'cat <( echo foo )'`)

Comment: It doesn't work if I escape the parentheses. Yes my command prompt is using bash. How would I force perl to use bash?

Comment: You are running `perl`. Why not use its facility to parse the file instead of `system`, `sed` and `tail`?

Comment: Re "*How would I force perl to use bash?*", The same way you are "forcing it" to use `sed`: `\`bash -c '...'\``

Comment: I hope after everything's written and done it doesn't end up like `system("bash -c 'perl ...')")`.

Comment: alvits: I plan on using this from a remote machine while launching a SOAP service on a server. I execute a command to start up a SOAP service on a group of servers (one box at a time), and I have to wait for each one to complete before moving on to the next one. The plan would be to (from perl) system("ssh <IP_ADDRESS> sed \$message\ exec tail -f...") and this process will continue to execute until that message is seen (or a 10 minute timer is hit). I'm open to suggestions if you know of a better way. Also, it's will not be written like system("bash -c 'perl ...')"),

Comment: You won't need `system()` then. You can simply send the remote commands using [Net::SSH Perl Module](http://search.cpan.org/~schwigon/Net-SSH-Perl-2.12/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm)

Comment: @alvits: I don't have control over any of the system, or ability to install any perl modules. I used @ikegami's info that it wasn't being executed from a bash shell, and I eventually ended with this code:     
 `my $tail_command = qq{sed '/$soap_message/ q' <(sudo ssh <IP_ADDRESS> exec tail -n +0 -f $supervisor_soap_log); kill \$! 2> /dev/null;};  
&bash($tail_command); 
  sub bash { return `cat << 'EOF' | /bin/bash\n$_[0]\nEOF\n`; }

Comment: You don't need to install any perl modules on the target servers. You only need it on your localhost. In fact, you are not running any perl script on the target servers. Or maybe you meant that you cannot install perl modules on your localhost.

Comment: @altvits: Understood, I was just trying to be thorough in describing what I have control over. I don't have the ability to install modules on localhost OR the targets.

Comment: I encourage that you post it as an answer for future readers that has the same question.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to print your command before feeding it to `system` it will save you a lot of troubles, I always to it.

Running

```
$> perl -de 1  
DB> $tail_command = qq{sed \'/SOAP service initialization completed/ q\' <(exec tail -n +0 -f /Users/xxxx/Desktop/sample.txt); kill \$! 2> /dev/null;};
DB> print $tail_command
```

I get in output:

```
sed '/SOAP service initialization completed/ q' <(exec tail -n +0 -f /Users/xxxx/Desktop/sample.txt); kill $! 2> /dev/null;
```

Which does not correspond to your original string. You must add some escape chars.

Answer (score 0):

The proper answer was that perl was invoking sh rather than bash, and it wasn't recognizing the code (thanks @ikegami for pointing that out). So in order to execute this in a bash shell I did the following:

```
my $tail_command = qq{sed '/$soap_message/ q' <(sudo ssh <IP_ADDRESS> exec tail -n +0 -f $supervisor_soap_log); 
kill \$! 2> /dev/null;}; 
&bash($tail_command);   
sub bash { return cat << 'EOF' | /bin/bash\n$_[0]\nEOF\n`; }
```